# mysql timezone is set to system but shows wrong time

Tags: php, mysql, time, timezone

My server's time is correct, also php's too. But I cannot get my mysql to show the correct time.

```
generateJSON(Array( 'timezone' => date_default_timezone_get(), 
                        'time_php' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
                        'time_mysql'=> mysql_result(mysql_query('SELECT NOW()'),0),
                        'mysql_session_timezone' => mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT @@session.time_zone"), 0),
                        'mysql_global_timezone' => mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT @@global.time_zone"), 0)
                ));
```

Result

```
{
timezone: "Europe/Istanbul",
time_php: "2015-09-15 11:36:06",
time_mysql: "2015-09-15 04:36:06",
mysql_session_timezone: "SYSTEM",
mysql_global_timezone: "SYSTEM"
}
```

**Edit:** As a comment suggested added `@@global.system_time_zone`

```
{
timezone: "Europe/Istanbul",
time_php: "2015-09-15 13:17:08",
time_mysql: "2015-09-15 06:17:08",
mysql_session_timezone: "SYSTEM",
mysql_global_timezone: "SYSTEM",
mysql_global_system_time_zone: "EEST"
}
```

Comment: Check also time zone of server, where MySql is running: [`SELECT @@global.system_time_zone`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html) (it's used because `@@session.time_zone='SYSTEM'`)

Comment: @Rimas added. It also points to correct timezone. I restarted mysql service in case it didn't fetch some changes. Nothing changed.

Comment: EEST isn't a timezone name - acronyms are just convenience names with hard-coded assignments. In fact, from the offset it looks like the timezone is set to US Eastern Standard Time (EST). Is your server hosted on the cloud or a US host? Or perhaps the computer uses a US locale or timezone?

Comment: its located on germany. Even though restarting the mysql service itself didn't solve the issue, rebooting the server solved the time difference between the server and the mysql. Everything looks fine now.